# C++ Can't retrieve private variable from class

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization, undefined-behavior

I am writing a program that generates integers and sets the range of the user's choosing.

For example:

```
Enter the number of integers: 4 
Range: 10
```

`4 9 2 1 are generated` 
Now the user chooses 4 digits at a time until they're correct. 
Program will also tell user if they are partially correct.
For example:

```
User input: 4 9 0 7

Console << 2 of your answers are correct.
```

I have three files: 
Driver.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Game.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Declare variables.
    Guess guess;
    int numberOfIntegers;
    int rangeOfIntegers;
    int count = guess.getSum();
    //Prompt user input.
    while(count != numberOfIntegers) {
        cout << "Enter the Number of Integers (n): " << endl;
        cin >> numberOfIntegers;
        cout << "Number of Each Integers from 1 to (m): " << endl;
        cin >> rangeOfIntegers;
        cout << "Enter your guesses for the " << numberOfIntegers << " integers in the range from 1 to " << rangeOfIntegers << " that have been selected:" << endl;
        guess.beginGuessingGame(rangeOfIntegers, numberOfIntegers);
    }
     if (count == numberOfIntegers) {
            cout << "You are correct! Play again? (y/n)";
        }
        else {
            cout << count << " of your guesses are correct." << endl;
        }

};
```

Game.h

```
// identifiers
#ifndef guessing_game
#define guessing_game

class Guess
{
     private :
          int * generatedSequence;
          int * inputGuess;
          int sum;
     public :
          void generateSequence(int inputRangeOfIntegers, int inputNumberOfIntegers);
          void beginGuessingGame(int inputRangeOfIntegers, int inputNumberOfIntegers);
          int getSum() {
              return sum;
          }
};
#endif
```

and Game.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include <iomanip>

#include "Game.h"

using namespace std;

void Guess::generateSequence(int inputRangeOfIntegers, int inputNumberOfIntegers) {
  /// Initialize random number generator.
  srand(time(0));

  /// Declare array size for the generated sequence to be based on user input.
  generatedSequence = new int[inputRangeOfIntegers];

  /// Input randomly generated numbers from from 0 to input range into generatedSequence.
  for (int i = 0; i < inputNumberOfIntegers; i++) {
    generatedSequence[i] = rand() % inputRangeOfIntegers + 1;
    cout << generatedSequence[i] << " " << endl;
  }
}

void Guess::beginGuessingGame(int inputRangeOfIntegers, int inputNumberOfIntegers) {
  /// Call our generateSequence function.
  generateSequence(inputRangeOfIntegers, inputNumberOfIntegers);

  /// Declare guess size based on user input.
  inputGuess = new int[inputNumberOfIntegers];

  /// Begin endless loop for user to guess integers.
  for (;;) {
    for (int i = 0; i < inputNumberOfIntegers; i++) {
      cin >> inputGuess[i];
    }

    /// If the user has found the random sequence, we can make sum equal to the number of integers.
    sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputNumberOfIntegers; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < inputNumberOfIntegers; j++) {
        /// If the user has entered the right guess, we can tally sum to the number of integers entered.
        if (generatedSequence[i] == inputGuess[j]) {
          sum++;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My issue is: I cant retrieve that sum variable in the main class to check it against the number of integers. Because if they are equal, then the program knows the user has guessed correctly. I cant use cout after calling the beginGuessingGame function either..

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Why have you made something you want access to from outside of the class `private`?

Comment: @ScottHunter The assignment states that we must use "data hiding". Would this be an exception?

Comment: Why can't you use `getSum`?

Answer (score 1):

At least this part of the program

```
Guess guess;
int numberOfIntegers;
int rangeOfIntegers;
int count = guess.getSum();

//Prompt user input.
while(count != numberOfIntegers) {    //...
```

does not make sense. The program has undefined behavior.

Data members of the class object `guess` are not initialized  So the member function `getSum` returns an indeterminate value of the data member `sum` of the object. And this indeterminate value is compared with another indeterminate value of the uninitialized variable `numberOfIntegers` in the while loop.

In the function `generateSequence` it seems there is a typo in this statement

```
generatedSequence = new int[inputRangeOfIntegers];
```

There should be

```
generatedSequence = new int[inputNumberOfIntegers];
```

Within the function `beginGuessingGame` there is an infinite loop

```
  for (;;) {
    for (int i = 0; i < inputNumberOfIntegers; i++) {
      cin >> inputGuess[i];
    }

    /// If the user has found the random sequence, we can make sum equal to the number of integers.
    sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputNumberOfIntegers; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < inputNumberOfIntegers; j++) {
        /// If the user has entered the right guess, we can tally sum to the number of integers entered.
        if (generatedSequence[i] == inputGuess[j]) {
          sum++;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Changed it to while(true), same result.

Comment: @xigedi20 See my appended post. And your code in main does not make sense. For example the variable count is not initialized. So close this question selecting the best answer and rewrite your program anew taking into account what I wrote in my answer.